# How do I copy a Shape from one Powerpoint presentation to another in VBA?

Tags: vba, powerpoint, copy-paste

I have VBA code to copy shapes matching a certain criteria from one Powerpoint presentation to another below.  However, when it pastes the shape, it is offset (down and to the right) from the original position.  How can I copy a shape while maintaining the original coordinates?

```
sourceShape.Copy
Presentations(2).Windows(1).Activate
ActivePresentation.Slides(x).Shapes.Paste (1)
```

Comment: Try using `.Duplicate` instead of `.Copy`

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps simply:

```
Shape s=ActivePresentation.Slides(x).Shapes.Paste (1)

s.Left=sourceShape.Left

s.Top=sourceShape.Top
```