# Store and restore clipboard data

Tags: c#, winforms, clipboard

I need to use the clipboard for my own purposes.
But I want to restore the previous clipboard state after using it.

I tried to do something like this:

```
var tmp = Clipboard.GetDataObject();
// My work with clipboard
Clipboard.SetDataObject(tmp);
```

But the clipboard is empty after this.
What did I miss?

Comment: Have you tried to clear the Clipboard before setting the data back?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2578900/how-do-i-backup-and-restore-the-system-clipboard-in-c

Comment: Now I try to do it (`Clipboard.Clear();` before `SetDataObject` ). Same result.

Comment: I think this has already been answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6262454/c-sharp-backing-up-and-restoring-clipboard